# BootStrap V3 carousel does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

this is my carousel in a a webform with master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/GUOTS.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="../Images/Design/facebook.png" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <img src="../Images/Design/linkedin.png" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <img src="../Images/Design/yahoo.jpg" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <img src="../Images/Design/linkedin.png" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GUOTS.master.cs" Inherits="GUOTS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>سامانه آزمون آنلاین دانشگاه گلستان</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="background-color: #f7f7f7" class="container">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the first photo is fixed and there is no sliding and even changing of the photos.
I'm using visual studio 2012 and asp.net with C# and BootStrap V3.0.3.

what is the problem??

thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: what do you mean console?

Comment: I'm new to asp.net and bootstrap. i think the bootstrap.js is not placed correctly