# BootStrap 3 carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
        <div>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="Images/Design/facebook.png" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>...</h3>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item ">
                        <img src="Images/Design/linkedin.png" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>...</h3>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item ">
                        <img src="Images/Design/yahoo.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>...</h3>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item ">
                        <img src="Images/Design/Mahdi_Hesari@YMail.com.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>...</h3>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

i think every thing is ok and it have to work. but it's not working even when i click on next and prev buttons.
where is the problem?

i'm using bootsrap version v 3.0.3 in visual studio 2012.

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include first jQuery library, then bootstrap.js:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Likely, you are currently getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: thank you very much. here is almost same problem. can you solve this too? thank you again :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761607/bootstrap-v3-carousel-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the order in wihch you include the jquery/boostrap js files. Bootstrap has jquery as a prerequisite, so it needs to find it there by the time it's loaded.